# formato de columna en archico csv

Tags: php

estoy descargando una base de datos la cual tiene campos de estado, municipio y parroquia y cada uno de ellos tiene un código único al hacer la consulta a la base de datos me llegan los código de la siguiente manera : código_estado = 01, código_municipio = 01 pero al generarse el csv a estos códigos se les elimina el 0, cuando se abren con excel o con calc.

esta es la funcion que me genera el csv

```
function generarCsv($mayor5){
   $lista = array();
   foreach ($mayor5 as $cp) {
        foreach ($cp as $titulo => $value) {
           array_push($lista, $titulo);
        }
    break;

   }

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"Base de Datos.csv\""); 

    //preparar el wrapper de salida
    $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');   

    //volcamos el contenido del array en formato csv
    fputcsv($outputBuffer,$lista, ';');

        foreach($mayor5 as $codigo_persona  => $data) {
            foreach ($data as $i => $valor) {
                $data[$i] = utf8_decode($valor);
            }               
            if($codigo_persona!=""){
                fputcsv($outputBuffer,$data, ';');    
            }                
        }
    //cerramos el wrapper
    fclose($outputBuffer);
    exit;
    $this->index();
}
```

este es el arreglo como me llega de la base de datos 
los campos en negrita son los que al momento de generar el archico

```
[fecha_registro] => 2018-03-13 14:39:23.51861
[codigo_origen] => 1
[origen] => Plan Vulnerabilidad
[codigo_persona] => PER0106
**[cedula_ubicacion] => 0101020010000003**
**[codigo_estado] => 01**
[estado] => DISTRITO CAPITAL
**[codigo_municipio] => 01**
[nombre_municipio] => LIBERTADOR
**[codigo_parroquia] => 02**
[nombre_parroquia] => ANTIMANO
**[codigo_sector] => 001**
[nombre_sector] => EL SIFON
[nombres_apellidos] => NOEMI AGUIRRE
[cedula] => 2
[fecha_nacimiento] => 1950-11-10
[edad] => 67
[meses] => 4
[dias] => 3
[codigo_genero] => 2
[embarazo] => 1
[cbi] => 200
[peso] => 54.3
[talla] => 1.55
[codigo_descripcion_situacion] => 1`
```

Uso la función de php **fputcsv**. ¿Cómo podría solventar este caso?

Comment: Angel, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/149496/edit)  colocando el código que estás usando, para que puedas recibir una mejor ayuda. Quizá estás parseando los datos a entero en PHP o algo así. Con el código se verá más claro. Gracias.

Comment: Lo siento @AngelGuitierrez, pero al ser un archivo CSV no se guardan los tipos de datos de cada celda, por lo que Excel interpreta que esos datos son numéricos y, por defecto, para datos numéricos Excel elimina los ceros a la izquierda. Si quieres mantenerlos deberás generar un archivo excel con alguna clase (como [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)) que te permita definir el tipo de contenido y marcarlo (forzarlo) como contenido de "texto" para que su contenido no sea modificado.

Answer (score 0):

Realicé unas pruebas, y entrecomillar el número más anteponer el signo igual al número con ceros a la izquierda, me resultó para que Excel respete dicho formato cuando abre o importa datos desde un CSV. En tu caso, sería hacer algo como:

```
// así viene de la BD:
            [cedula_ubicacion] => 0101020010000003

// así lo guardas en csv:
            ="0101020010000003"

// o sea, si hablamos de PHP:
           $valor = '="0101020010000003"';
```